# Accessing pointer not in memory

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, rtos, null-pointer

Error on line

```
ptr = (PTR)(event->LINK.NEXT);
```

Error: Cannot access pointer on memory. Dereferencing a null pinter event->LINK.NEXT

Comparing data to null implies that kernel->LINK.NEXT might be null.
I can see why it is giving that error. But how do I change the code so that dereferencing error is not displayed.

```
   KERNEL(data);
   event_ptr->VALUE = 0;
   event_ptr->FLAGS = flags;
   _int_disable();
   if (kernel_data->LINK.NEXT == NULL) {
      _QUEUE_INIT(&kernel_data->LINK, 0);
   } /* Endif */



   while (ptr != (PTR)(kernel_data->NEXT)) {
         enable();
         Juble() 
        return(MQX_EINVAL);
      } 
      ptr = (PTR)(event->LINK.NEXT);
   } /* Endwhile */
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that `event_chk_ptr` is non-NULL before trying to use it. This will stop the loop when you reach the end of the linked list:

```
   while (event_chk_ptr && event_chk_ptr != (LWEVENT_STRUCT_PTR)((pointer)&kernel_data->LWEVENTS)) {
    ...
   }
```